# Javascript append data to not currently active HTML doc

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

```
    function updateTable(data1, data2) {
        var table = document.getElementById("placeWhereUpdateNeeded");
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data1));
        td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data2));
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        table.appendChild(tr);
     }
```

Problem is that the Id("placeWhereUpdateNeeded") is in another HTML document (not the currently active one). Is it even possible to add the data to another HTML doc? Currently that code would search for the Id in the active HTML (where it doesn't exist). So basically, is it possible to specify a HTML document where getElementById searches for the Id? I realize it's a very silly issue, I've only started learning. Any help welcome!

Comment: If you open it with ajax, then yes. Are you using jQuery? It would make it much easier.

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with jQuery or any other frameworks for that matter. Could you specify a source where I can read about this more?

Comment: Where is the other document open? Is it in an iframe?

Comment: @James If you do not know what you are doing (yet) please do not start using libraries. I would call christian's advice terrible at best.

Comment: @Peehaa jQuery actually makes it more easy to use javascript, you only have to know the basics of js to get it working.

Comment: "you only have to know the basics of js to get it working" Exactly my point. People should not start with using frameworks / libraries before they know what they are doing. This is for JS, PHP and whatever language I have encountered.

Comment: Yeah, people should know what they're doing, but that's what jQuery and other libraries are for, to make it easier. Imagine a webdesigner to code a simple slideIn / slideOut?